# How to model structural break in ARIMAX/VAR/ARDL

Tags: time-series, arima, vector-autoregression, ardl

I tried to use a QLR test for structural breaks for a variable that I am forecasting, and I found a break, which is very accurate to geopolitical events in 2022.
Because of this, my significance of some exogenous variables in the model (ARIMAX) changes depending on the size of the training sample.
I'd like to capture this break somehow since I'm only using variations of the AR model and since it makes economic sense, but as far as I know I can't use results of it straightforward with ARIMAX/VAR/ARDL models due to the limitations of the QLR test.
Are there any test for structural breaks for these models that I can use?
Can I use a dummy in this case? If so, is it worth mentioning the QLR test results based on AR(1) process?